# How to import Google's libphonenumber library into KMP common"

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I would like to import [[libphonenumber]](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber) into the 'common' part of a KMP project, but Kotlin can't import it.  I see the library added twice to the external libraries after I added the [maven](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/libphonenumber/8.12.6/) url.  But, the import in Kotlin can't resolve the library, so I can't use the libraries classes.  What am I missing?

Comment: How did you achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libphonenumber isn't a Kotlin Multiplatform library. It seems to support many platforms, so you could write library wrappers for Kotlin.

I gave a talk about writing platform wrapper libraries: https://vimeo.com/371460823

If the target for native is C++, you'll likely need to write some C wrappers. Just FYI.

Answer (score -1):

Started a port of kotlin multiplaform port of libphonenumber here https://github.com/luca992/libphonenumber-kotlin